# does buoyancy depend on orientation?

Tags: buoyancy

Let's say we have a sheet of steel of 1m^2 that is relatively thin. Will the buoyancy be the same if the sheet is fully immersed and placed horizontally inside the fluid with the buoyancy if the sheet is vertically?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the buoyancy depends only on the displaced volume (strictly speaking, the weight of the displaced liquid).

Note that if you have a compressible shape (a balloon, perhaps), then the object may occupy a different volume depending on the orientation; this change in volume would then affect the buoyancy.

But for a sheet of steel that doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes.  A similar caveat applies in the case of a compressible fluid (gas), as well.

Comment: @DuncanHarris good point - it would have a density gradient